# Angular.js binding event handle to element using $browser.defer

Tags: angularjs

I am angular.js beginner. Can anyone explain me in detail what is done in code below? What is $browser and what $browser.defer(listenerOnKey) is supposed to do (remaining code is pretty clear)?

```
element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
    var key = event.keyCode
    // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, C, V or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
    if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40) || key == 67 || key == 86 || key == 9 || key == 8 || key == 46 || key == 190 || key ==110 )
        return
            $browser.defer(listenerOnKey);
})

var listenerOnKey = function () {
    var value = element.val().replace(/,/g, '').replace('%', '');
    element.val($filter('number')(value));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vladimir noted, it's not public API, so you shouldn't use it. It's something used internally within AngularJS.

> Also, `$browser.defer` Executes a fn asynchronously via `setTimeout(fn, delay)`.

So instead of using that, simply do it yourself using `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(listenerOnKey, 0);
```

---

As for what the code itself does, it doesn't do anything if they hit those certain keys, but every other key it calls the function `listenerOnKey` below, which removes any `comma's` or `%` signs.

After it does that it then runs an angularJS filter testing to see if the value is in fact a `number`.

```
element.val($filter('number')(value));
```

If not, it returns an empty string and clears the input.

Comment: Ok, you answered the second part of the question. But what is the logic behind the if statement? What does this piece of code do when the input keys are, let's say 'a','b','9' etc. and what if the input key is 'ctrl','alt'...(all the keys included in the comment)?

Comment: Ok thank you! Only one more simple question about javascript. Would the code be the same if I put a semicolon after the return statement - return;

Comment: Yes, that'd be the same. Try to always use a semi-colon, this code looks like someone was trying to shave a few characters (but honestly there's no reason to do that). Also you should try to always have brackets `if () { /* code*/  }` for an if statement, it looks confusing otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

$browser service is not a 'public' Angular API, so I would advise to avoid any code that uses it. Especially if youre a beginner